# How to control a NSView, located in a dedicated NSWindow, from the main NSWindow designed to support the GUI built under COCOA?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is probably a simple problem for the high skilled Cocoa programmers, but I can't find how to control the graph in a separate window. I read carefully the Cocoa related books, go through many web notes,but I can't find a solution to my problem. The purpose is to use a dedicated window to draw the I=F(Vg) curves extracted by the GUI from a specific hardware. All the GUI and the hardware works fine ( thanks to the help provided by several members of stackoverflow) , but no way to send the parameters to the NSView to display the results.
So far, the GUI class is based on a NSObject, the graphic class is NSView.
Any idea, examples, links will be appreciated. Thank you so much.
Michael

Answer (score 1):

So you have a controller class that receives data and owns a window? Just give it an outlet to the view.

This is the job of the controller in [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html): To pass data from the model (in this case, the hardware connection) to the views.